# Why isn't the AvroCoder deterministic?

Tags: avro, google-cloud-dataflow

[AvroCoder.isDeterministic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/6ad521097f50d6390ba99489d0dffb87c9991715/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) returns false.

Why isn't the AvroCoder deterministic? Wouldn't Avro records always be encoded into the same byte stream?

Since the Avro Coder isn't deterministic an Avro record can't be used as a Key for a group by operation. What's the best way to turn an Avro record into a key? Should we just use the json representation of the Avro record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [Avro specification](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html) it looks like only Arrays and Maps have non deterministic binary encoding.

Maps look like they are non deterministically encoded for two reasons

- The order of the elements isn't specified
- The blocks can be encoded two different ways either by specifying the number of elements or the number of bytes in the block.

Arrays look like they are non deterministically encoded because

- The block can be encoded two different ways either by specifying the number of elements or the number of bytes in the block.

So for any schema without an array or a map, I think the binary encoding should be deterministic. So I think we could create a deterministic encoder just by subclassing [AvroCoder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/6ad521097f50d6390ba99489d0dffb87c9991715/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) and overriding [AvroCoder.isDeterministic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/6ad521097f50d6390ba99489d0dffb87c9991715/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) to return true.

[AvroDeterministicCoder](https://bitbucket.org/jlewi/dataflow/src/3fc7ae6d353fd8457d757eac72322ec2f768a6e5/dataflow/src/main/java/dataflow/AvroDeterministicCoder.java?at=master) is my first attempt at creating such a coder.

Answer (score 1):

`AvroCoder` can inspect the schema and type being coded and decide when it is deterministic. It was added in GitHub commit [#a806df](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/a806df86c59840f433da871ee4d96dcfc648ecb0).

It includes support for deterministically encoding arrays and maps when the underlying collection is deterministically order.

Comment: Could you please clarify this answer?  I am designing some data structures that I want to be able to deterministically encode, so that I will always get the same hash.  If any arrays and maps I use are inherently ordered, can I be sure the avro encoding will be deterministic?

Answer (score 0):

An Avro POJO generated from Schema implements Serializable indirectly.

This means that, even if it is deterministic, it still cannot be used as a key, e.g. for `CoGroupByKey` or `GroupByKey`, because Beam rejects any Serializable type outright as being non-deterministic.