# Can I compare the serialized representation of records in unittests?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In the unittest for my DoFo, is it possible to assert the output matches the expected output by comparing the serialized representations of the records?

I've defined a record which uses a default avro coder e.g

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class JobLogMessage {
  @Nullable
  public String projectId;

  ...
}
```

I'm writing a unittest for a DoFn that uses DoFnTester to produce a list of JobLogMessage's e.g.

```
JogLogTransforms.ParsJsonDoFn doFn = new JogLogTransforms.ParsJsonDoFn();
DoFnTester<String, JobLogMessage> fnTester = DoFnTester.of(doFn);
List<JobLogMessage> outputs = fnTester.processBatch(inputs.toArray(new String[inputs.size()]));
```

I'd like to verify that outputs matches the expected outputs. However if I just use assertEquals I think that will use the equals method which won't correctly evaluate equality unless I explicitly overload equals in JobLogMessage.

What I'd like to do is compare the expected and actual JobLogMessage's by comparing the serialized byte representations produced by AvroCoder. Does Dataflow produce any convenience methods for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with the limitation of requiring a deterministic schema, you can simplify the code somewhat to make better use of the utilities available in the SDK and JDK.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (!(obj instanceof JobLogMessage)) {
    return false;
  }

  JobLogMessage other = (JobLogMessage) obj;
  AvroCoder<JobLogMessage> coder = AvroCoder.of(JobLogMessage.class);
  return Arrays.equals(CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(this, coder),
                       CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(obj, coder));
}
```

**That said, I think it's much better** to use something like [EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from apache commons-lang which were explicitly designed for your goals (coders weren't designed for being used as hashers and equality testers) - just use `return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented equals using AvroCoder to produce serialized representations and then compare the serialized representations.

```
 @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof JobLogMessage)) {
      return false;
    }

    JobLogMessage other = (JobLogMessage) obj;
    AvroCoder<JobLogMessage> coder = AvroCoder.of(JobLogMessage.class);

    Coder.Context context = new Coder.Context(true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream thisStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      coder.encode(this, thisStream, context);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("There was a problem encoding the object.", e);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream otherStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      coder.encode(other, otherStream, context);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("There was a problem encoding the object.", e);
    }

    byte[] theseBytes = thisStream.toByteArray();
    byte[] otherBytes = otherStream.toByteArray();

    if (theseBytes.length != otherBytes.length) {
      return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < theseBytes.length; ++i) {
      if (theseBytes[i] != otherBytes[i]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a correct implementation in general, because the Avro coder is not deterministic - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129664/why-isnt-the-avrocoder-deterministic . Is there any reason why you don't want to implement an equals() and hashCode() method for JobLogMessage explicitly?

Comment: An equals method would have to be updated every time I add a field to my record. I'd prefer something more general. I'm ok with the limitation that this is only valid in the context of deterministic schemas. I think that is consistent with what DataflowAssert would do.

Comment: Based on a quick reading of DataflowAssert, I don't think it uses serialization to compare objects for equality. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/testing/DataflowAssert.java , in the end, derives from AssertThatIterable, which uses regular equals/hashCode methods.